# Haskell: Something like the application `$` operator for "do" notation?

Tags: haskell

I'm supplying a function to `idleCallback` This notation works:

```
idleCallback $= Just (do
    modifyIORef world play
    postRedisplay Nothing)
```

Why doesn't this (seemingly similar) notation work?

```
idleCallback $= Just $ do
    modifyIORef world play
    postRedisplay Nothing
```

To save your hoogling, the types are:

```
($=) :: HasSetter s => s a -> a -> IO ()
type IdleCallback = IO ()
data SettableStateVar a 
idleCallback :: SettableStateVar (Maybe IdleCallback)
postRedisplay :: Maybe Window -> IO ()
modifyIORef :: IORef a -> (a -> a) -> IO ()
```

GHC says:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Maybe IdleCallback'
            with actual type `a0 -> Maybe a0'
In the second argument of `($=)', namely `Just'
In the expression: idleCallback $= Just
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  idleCallback $= Just
  $ do { modifyIORef world play;
         postRedisplay Nothing }
```

Can this be written without wrapping the `do` block in parenthesis?

Comment: This kind of problem is common in people who think `$` is special. It's not. It's just another library-defined infix operator. It follows precedence rules the same as every other library-defined infix operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a precedence error....  (`$=`) is binding more tightly than (`$`).  You can see this in the error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Maybe IdleCallback'
        with actual type `a0 -> Maybe a0'
In the second argument of `($=)', namely `Just'
```

It thinks that the second argument of (`$=`) is simply `Just` (which is a valid Haskell type referencing a function).  If you put parenthesis around the whole `Just`, including the `do`-block, it should work.

Comment: Indeed that works. But, is there a way to write it without wrapping the `do` block in parenthesis?

Comment: It isn't the same thing you did above...  I am wrapping the whole "Just" expression in parenthesis :), but I feel your pain, it isn't pretty.  You might want to try (idleCallback $=) $ Just $ do....  This isn't so pretty either, but at least you don't have a dangling parenthesis.  You could also redifine a second $= with different precedence (for instance, create a ($==)).

Answer (score 2):

`$` isn't special notation for saving parentheses, it's an ordinary function (with an infix operator). As such, it *can't* mean "wrap parentheses around everything to the right". What it actually means is "apply my first argument to my second argument".
As such, it's often useful for saving parentheses, but not here because this:

```
idleCallback $= Just $ do
    modifyIORef world play
    postRedisplay Nothing
```

Would be rewritten using no `$` and more parentheses as this:

```
(idleCallback $= Just) (do
    modifyIORef world play
    postRedisplay Nothing)
```

Rather than what you wanted. The reason is that it's in fact parsed as this, once you've transformed the operator precedence/associativity notation to explicit form:

```
($) (idleCallback $= Just) (do
    modifyIORef world play
    postRedisplay Nothing)
```

The core problem is that `$=` also isn't special syntax, but an ordinary function (with infix notation), and `$` simply has lower precedence than `$=`; `$` by design has extremely low precedence; this is what makes it often work for parentheses-reduction in normal code, but also often what makes it fail when you move a correct expression involving `$` into a new context as part of a larger expression.

The only fully general way to make such a transformation (which is what you're doing implicitly when you reason that `Just $ do ...` works, so `idleCallback $= Just $ do ...` should also work) is to wrap the full expression in parentheses before you insert it into the outer expression (which would yield `idleCallback $= (Just $ do ...)`, which indeed works fine). This is actually the case for all expressions, particularly when operators are involved. e.g. You would know automatically that just because `x + y` works doesn't mean it will still work the way you want when you drop it into the blank in `z * ___` ; you have to either blindly parenthesise to get `z * (x + y)`, or else reason about the specific code on a case by case basis to see whether and where you need parentheses (or other transformations).

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage may vary as to whether it is better, but one thing that should work unless `$=` has the very highest precedence is

```
idleCallback $= Just `id` do
...
```

This works because `id` as operator has no precedence defined, so gets the highest by default.

Comment: Perhaps a better workaround would be to define a custom infix e.g. `($=@) :: (HasSetter v) => v (Maybe a) -> a -> IO ()`. Or write `(idleCallback$=) . Just $ do ...`. But yours isn't that bad either, IMO.